# basename and homepage not working as expected to serve /static/ files in development

Tags: reactjs, docker, kubernetes, react-router-dom, nginx-ingress

Not sure if this is a Kubernetes, `ingress-nginx`, or ReactJS (`create-react-app`) issue...

**Project Structure**

```
new-app/
  client/
    src/
      App.js
      index.js
      Test.js
    package.json
  k8s/
    client.yaml
    ingress.yaml
  server/
  skaffold.yaml
```

**Issue**

- ReactJS front-end should be running at `192.168.64.5/client` when the cluster is spun up with Skaffold
- Navigate to `192.168.64.5/client` and blank screen
- Developer Console shows:

[image]
[image]

Basically, it is trying to serve static files from `/static`, but I need them to come from `/client/static`

**Propsed Solutions**

Assuming this is a ReactJS issue, the solutions have been the following:

- Setting `homepage` in the `package.json`
- Setting `basename` in the `react-router-dom`
- Following [this "elegant" solution](https://skryvets.com/blog/2018/09/20/an-elegant-solution-of-deploying-react-app-into-a-subdirectory/)

None seem to work in my case. Still shows assets trying to be served from `/static` instead of `/client/static`.

**ReactJS App Code**

```
// App.js

import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import './App.css';

import Test from './Test';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter
      basename='/client'>
        <>
          <Route exact path='/' component={Test} />
        </>
    </BrowserRouter>

  );
}

export default App;
```

```
// Test.js

import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import axios from 'axios';

const Test = () => {

  const [data, setData] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await axios('/api/auth/test/');
      setData(result.data);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className='App'>
    <header className='App-header'>
      <img src={logo} className='App-logo' alt='logo' />
      <p>
        Edit <code>src/App.js</code> and save to reload!
      </p>
      <p>
        {data}
      </p>
      <a
        className='App-link'
        href='https://reactjs.org'
        target='_blank'
        rel='noopener noreferrer'
      >
        Learn React
      </a>
    </header>
    </div>    
  )

};

export default Test;
```

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "homepage": "/client",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

**Kubernetes/Skaffold and Docker Manifests**

```
# Dockerfile.dev

FROM node:alpine
EXPOSE 3000
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY ./client/package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./client .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

```
# ingress.yaml

apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/add-base-url: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /client/?(.*)
            backend:
              serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service
              servicePort: 3000
```

```
# client.yaml

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      component: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        component: client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: clientappcontainers.azurecr.io/client
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-cluster-ip-service
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  selector:
    component: client
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

```
# skaffold.yaml

apiVersion: skaffold/v1beta15
kind: Config
build:
  local:
    push: false
  artifacts:
    - image: clientappcontainers.azurecr.io/client
      docker:
        dockerfile: ./client/Dockerfile.dev
      sync:
        manual:
          - src: "***/*.js"
            dest: .
          - src: "***/*.html"
            dest: .
          - src: "***/*.css"
            dest: .
deploy:
  kubectl:
    manifests:
      - manifests/ingress.yaml 
      - manifests/client.yaml
```

So what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT:**

I should note that things work fine when doing this though:

```
- path: /?(.*)
  backend:
    serviceName: client-cluster-ip-service
    servicePort: 3000
```

Repo to demo the issue:

https://github.com/eox-dev/subdir-issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this is not possible currently in CRA in a dev environment:

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8222#issuecomment-568308139

Answer (score 0):

> Create React App assumes your application is hosted at the serving web server's root or a subpath as specified in package.json (homepage). Normally, Create React App ignores the hostname. You may use this variable to force assets to be referenced verbatim to the URL you provide (hostname included). This may be particularly useful when using a CDN to host your application.

There are three ways to fix this problem:

1. Add your **basename** to the webpack output -> publicPath(If you *rejected* your create-react-app project and you have already access to the webpack config file)
2. Add PUBLIC_URL="/client" into **.env.production** file
3. Add **homepage** property into **package.json** file like this:

```js
{
  ...
  homepage: "/client"
  ...
}
```

Reference:

```sh
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/advanced-configuration/
```

Comment: I'm using `create-react-app` so don't have access to the `webpack.config.js` unless I `npm eject`.

Comment: I've updated my answer and I wrote to you how you can fix this problem.

Comment: OK, I've followed those steps along with several other things and still getting the same result: assets coming from `/static` instead of `/client/static`.

Comment: Which one have you implemented? another solution is adding PUBLIC_URL="/client" to the .env file instead of .env.production, file because this env variable uses just in production mode, whereas .env or .env.production should works as well as desired.

Comment: I've tried 2) and 3). I've also tried `PUBLIC_URL="/client"` in a `.env` and same thing. At this point I'm just trying with a `npm start` and skipping the entire `skaffold` and Kubernetes thing.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, to have a different homepage in production env, with CRA (or craco), you need to set

```
# .env.production
PUBLIC_URL="/client"
```

inside the file .env.production (or .env.development if root path different in dev) and than you change the basename of the Router:

```
<BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
  ...
</BrowserRouter>
```